# PHP no me guarda datos en la BBD MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

Bien, tengo una ficha de pagos para facturas. Uno de los campos es "Fecha" al que le tengo asociado un botón para que, al pulsar, me de la fecha de hoy. Correcto.

Creo una nueva columna en phpMyAdmin con los mismos parámetros que "FECHA" porque quiero añadir otro campo que se llame "Pago" para referirnos a la fecha en la que se ha realizado el pago. 
Bien, con la configuración siguiente, cuando le doy al botón "HOY" me modifica la fecha de la factura, pero el nuevo campo "pago" no se actualiza (no cambia y sigue con 000-00-00).

A ver si me podéis echar una mano (al cuello)

La estructura en la bbdd es:

Nombre: fecha
Tipo: Date
Predeterminado: Ninguno

La nueva: 
Nombre: pago
Tipo: Date
Predeterminado: Ninguno.

El php es este:

```
 <div class="table-overflow">
                        <?
                            $nomcolumns = array('ID','Fecha','Cliente','Correo','IRPF','IVA','Precio','Pagada','Fecha de Pago');
                            $nomcolumnsdb = array('idmostrado','fecha','cliente','correo','irpf','iva','precio','pagada','pago');

                            // type of the column
                            // text 1, select 2, radio boolean 3, textarea 4, date 5, 6 select clientes, 7 precio
                            $typecolumns = array(1,5,6,1,1,1,7,3,5);
                        ?>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-checks">
                            <tbody>
                            <?
                                $result = getclients();
                                for($i=0;$i<count($nomcolumns);$i++){?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th width="15%"><?=$nomcolumns[$i]?></th>
                                        <?
                                            switch($typecolumns[$i]){

                                                case 1:
                                                    {?><td><input type="text" name="<?=$nomcolumnsdb[$i]?>" value="<?=$factura[$nomcolumnsdb[$i]]?>" id="myinput"></td><?}
                                                    break;

                                                case 2:
                                                    {?><td><select name="<?=$nomcolumnsdb[$i]?>" id="myselectmonth"><?}
                                                    for($j=0;$j<count($valuesselect);$j++){
                                                        if($factura[$nomcolumnsdb[$i]]==$valuesselect[$j]){?><option value="<?=$valuesselect[$j]?>" selected><?=$namesselect[$j]?></option><?}
                                                        else{?><option value="<?=$valuesselect[$j]?>"><?=$namesselect[$j]?></option><?}
                                                    }
                                                    {?></select>
                                                    &nbsp;<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript:changemonth('myselectmonth',1)" value="Hoy"/>
                                                    </td><?}
                                                    break;

                                                case 3:
                                                    if($factura[$nomcolumnsdb[$i]]==0) $sel = array('checked','');
                                                    else $sel = array('','checked');
                                                    {?><td>
                                                        <input type="radio" name="<?=$nomcolumnsdb[$i]?>" value="0" <?=$sel[0]?>> No
                                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <input type="radio" name="<?=$nomcolumnsdb[$i]?>" value="1" <?=$sel[1]?>> S&iacute;
                                                        </td><?}
                                                    break;

                                                case 4:
                                                    {?><td><textarea class="ckeditor" name="<?=$nomcolumnsdb[$i]?>" rows="10" cols="97%"><?=$factura[$nomcolumnsdb[$i]]?></textarea> </td><?}
                                                    break;

                                                case 5:
                                                    {?><td><input type="date" name="<?=$nomcolumnsdb[$i]?>" value="<?=$factura[$nomcolumnsdb[$i]]?>" size="100%" id="datepicker" >
                                                    &nbsp;<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript:changedate('datepicker',1)" value="Hoy"/>
                                                    </td><?}
                                                    break;

                                                case 6:
                                                    {?><td><select name="<?=$nomcolumnsdb[$i]?>" id="myselect"><?}
                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                                        if($factura[$nomcolumnsdb[$i]]==$row['id']){?><option value="<?=$row['id']?>" selected><?=$row['razonsocial']?></option><?}
                                                        else{?><option value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['razonsocial']?></option><?}

                                                    }
                                                    {?></select>
                                                        </td><?}
                                                    mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
                                                    break;

                                                case 7:
                                                    {?><td><input type="text" name="<?=$nomcolumnsdb[$i]?>" value="<?=$factura[$nomcolumnsdb[$i]]?>" id="myinput">
                                                    &nbsp;<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript:updateprice('<?=$nomcolumnsdb[$i]?>','irpf','iva')" value="Actualizar"/>
                                                    </td><?}
                                                    break;


                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
```

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener e incorpora el código de tus intentos, cuando más breve y conciso mejor e intenta que quepa en la pantalla. Preferimos enseñarte a pescar que darte peces, si vemos lo que has intentado, podremos ayudarte a mejorar. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Es idea mia o en tu ejemplo no hay ningun `insert`? Sin eso, bastante dificil que guarde algo la base de datos.

Comment: @jolsalazar según lo que dice, se trataría de un `UPDATE`: *«cuando le doy al botón "HOY" me modifica la fecha de la factura, pero el nuevo campo "pago" no se actualiza (no cambia y sigue con 000-00-00)»*. Casi seguro que eso pasa porque el dato de la fecha que intenta enviarle no tiene el formato `YYYYMMDD`, cuando se manda un formato inválido toma el valor `0000-00-00`. Convendría de todos modos que diga cómo está definida la tabla y que muestre el código del `UPDATE`

Comment: Si, mi error. Lei quizas un poco rapido.